# Increasing the size of a plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

[image: image of a basic graph]

So I'm new to R (like within the past 3 days). I have this plot I've created- I'd like to make it *much* bigger so that there's enough space within the plot for the labels to be read legibly.

The labels *don't* have to be legible when I'm viewing the entire plot, I'm quite happy to zoom in quite a bit in order to read them.

I assume I would do this using GGplot2 but I'm a bit over my head.

I'm not doing anything complex with the graph, the code is just
`plot.igraph(g2, vertex.size = 2)`

Comment: It's easier to help you if you post sample data and your code. To show your sample data, type this and copy+paste the output in a code block -- head(df) %>% dput()

Comment: It depends on your output, i.e. whether you're saving to a bitmap image file or an SVG, whether it's being presented in an Rmarkdown document and what filetype that's rendering as, etc

Comment: @camille we decided to go for a PNG. Put the size right into the command.

Answer (score 1):

After consulting with a friend, we came up with the following solution (that works well)

In my data i have ~500 vertices and 25000 edges, just so people know but, we output a PNG image of 9k x 9k pixels. I made the vertices size 2, which meant that the labels could be read in the vertices at ~110% magnification

```
> png(file = "outfile.png", width = 9000, height = 9000, units = 'px')
```

> plot.igraph(g2, vertex.size =2,  edge.color = 'black')
> dev.off()

WARNING: the image generated is about 14MB. So too large to post. It'll give large images. But you can zoom in and see the labels